# Create a list using SWI-cpp.h

Tags: c++, swi-prolog

I'm trying to use the SWI-PL engine in C++ using `SWI-cpp.h`.
I don't have any tutorial, I'm only using [this reference](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section(%27packages/pl2cpp.html%27)) and I'm looking in GitHub repos for some examples.

My code works fine, except for one thing; calling this definition:
`foo([bar]).`
As you can see, the definition requires a list.

Since I can't put a `PlTermv` in a `PlTermv`, I have no idea how to construct a list. I could use a `PlTail`, but I only know a way in which I have to add an empty head.

This is my CPP code so far:

```
PlTermv av(1);

// Load external pl file that contaions the foo definition.
PlCall("consult", PlTerm("foobar.pl"));

PlAtom bar = PlAtom("hello");
// I want Prolog to return a list with this compound.
av[0] = PlCompound("foo", PlTermv(bar));
PlCall("call", av); // So that this statement returns 'true' instead of 'false'.
```

How could I change this code in a way that `PlCall("call",av);` returns`true`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating lists in Prolog can be done using the [atomic_list_concat/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=atomic_list_concat/3) predicate.

This means `PlCall` has to be called one more time in the code and it's result has to be stored in a `PlTerm`:

```
PlTermv av(1);

// Load external pl file that contaions the foo definition.
PlCall("consult", PlTerm("foobar.pl"));

PlTerm list;

// Use space as separator. Sets the value of 'list' to '[bar]'.
PlCall("atomic_list_concat", PlTermv(list, " ", "bar"));

av[0] = PlCompound("foo", PlTermv(list));
PlCall("call", av); // returns 'true'
```